# How to compute $\mathbb{P}(A|B)$ of two independent RVs?

Tags: conditional-probability, random-variable

There are two independent RVs $X \sim \mathcal{U}(-1,5)$ and $Y \sim \mathcal U(-5,5)$.

Let $A = \{ X \ge Y \land Y \ge -1 \land Y \le 1\}$ and $B = \{ X \le 1\}$.

What is $\mathbb P (A | B)$?

My idea is to apply Bayes' rule, i.e.

$$ \mathbb P(A|B) = \frac{\mathbb P(B|A) \mathbb P(A)}{\mathbb P(B|A)\mathbb P(A) + \mathbb P(B|\lnot A) \mathbb P(\lnot A)}$$

I understand that this works nicely as long as $\mathbb P(B|A)$ is easier to compute.

However, I find that

$$ \mathbb P(B|A) = \frac{\mathbb P(A|B) \mathbb P(B)}{\mathbb P(A|B)\mathbb P(B) + \mathbb P(A|\lnot B) \mathbb P(\lnot B)}$$

... which I feel does not bring me closer to the solution. The unconditional probabilities are fairly straight forward, but the conditional ones keep piling up.

How should I procede from there?

Comment: This is not a duplicate, although I agree it may appear very similar at first sight. In the other question, the entire $A$ is the condition.

Comment: It then shows you did not learn from the previous solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow your approach, note the definition of conditional probability $p(A|B) =\frac{p(A \land B)}{p(B)}$. Knowing this, one just need solve for $p(A \land B)$, as calculating $p(B)$ is straight-forward.

We're now looking for $A\land B = \{ X \ge Y \land Y \ge -1 \land Y \le 1 \land X \le 1\}$. Written to stress the ordering of values gives

$$A\land B = \{ Y \le X \land X \le 1 \land -1 \le Y \land Y \le 1 \}$$

Again by conditional probability:

$$p(A\land B) = p(\{ Y \le X | X \le 1 \land -1 \le Y \land Y \le 1 \}) p(\{X \le 1 \land -1 \le Y \land Y \le 1 \})$$

Since $X, Y$ are independent, the second term may be factored into the product $p(X\le 1)p(-1 \le Y  \le 1)$, and each factor can be calculated from its respective distribution. Solve for the first factor:

$$p(\{ Y \le X | X \le 1 \land -1 \le Y \land Y \le 1 \}) = \int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{x}\frac{dxdy}{4} = \frac{1}{4}\int_{-1}^1(x+1)dx = \frac{1}{2}$$

Combining all factors:

$$p(A|B) = \frac{p(A\land B)}{p(B)} $$
$$= \frac{p(\{ Y \le X | X \le 1 \land -1 \le Y \land Y \le 1 \}) p(X\le 1)p(-1 \le Y  \le 1)}{p(B)}$$

$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{5} = \frac{1}{10}$$

More intuitively: Knowing that $X \le 1$ turns the sample space into bivariate uniform on $x \in [-1,1], y \in [-5, 5]$; the total area of this space is $20$, and the area of the triangle bound by $y = -1, x = 1, y = x$ is $2$. An integral based on this approach gives an equivalent answer:

$$\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^{x}\frac{dx dy}{20} = \frac{1}{20}\int_{-1}^1(x+1)dx = \frac{1}{20}2= \frac{1}{10}$$